# Getting rid of empty JSON data iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I got a question, I'm creating an iOS app in objective-C and I'm parsing some JSON data. The issue is that the JSON data that it is returning has some empty strings in it which are causing an issue when displaying that data in the app, adding empty spaces on the table that isn't needed. The data looks like this for example (this is just one of the items were getting brackets aren't in this part)

```
TYPEID =     (
   "",
    1,
    1,
    1,
    "",
    "",
    "",
    1
);
```

How would I go about getting rid of the "", in the JSON data? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Create a new array from the original array. Simply leave out the undesired values.

Answer (score 1):

With `NSArray *originalArray = [yourObjectJSON objectForKey:@"TYPEID"];`

Try:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"length > 0"];
NSArray *filtered = [originalArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Can I use this with NSDictionary, thats how I'm currently passing the data.

Comment: I'd suggest that you use a `NSMutableDictionary`, filter your array, and then replace it in your `NSMutableDictionary` (`[yourDict setObject:filtered forKey:@"TYPEID"]`).